# How to add Swagger to a Jersey web app that only uses a ResourceConfig?

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, web.xml, swagger

We have started working on a web-app with a REST api and I found Swagger and I really want it... However, I am struggling to figure out how to add it in our app. The app is declared like this (hypothetical):

```
package hello.world;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

public class CloudApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public CloudApplication() {
        // Add all resources from hello.world
        packages("hello.world", "com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs");
    }
}
```

And the project has a web.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>hello.world</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>hello.world.CloudApplication</servlet-name>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>hello.world.CloudApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hw/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My pom.xml file contains

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs_2.9.1</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
...
```

Looking at https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/tree/master/samples, I find all the different setup, but I can't figure out which to use. https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/tree/master/samples/java-jaxrs seems like the right one, but can I keep the current project structure with just a resource config? /samples/java-jaxrs seems to require a lot of web.xml stuff... Can I do that in code instead? Any sample out there?

I do not have so much experience with web apps, but I would love to get this Swagger thing to work.

// Jonas

Answer (score 1):

Well, its a bit of pain. I ended up with the following, maybe it's just another setup that will confuse you, but maybe it works for you too:

I use a small bootstrap class to configure swagger like this:

```
public class SwaggerBootstrap extends HttpServlet {

    @Override public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) {

        ConfigFactory.config().setBasePath(basepath);
        ConfigFactory.config().setApiPath(apipath);
        ConfigFactory.config().setApiVersion(apiversion);
        ConfigFactory.config().setSwaggerVersion(com.wordnik.swagger.core.SwaggerSpec.version());
    }
}
```

My web.xml contains:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.listing</param-value>
</init-param>

<servlet>
   <servlet-name>JerseyJaxrsConfig</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>   
   <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SwaggerBootstrap</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>my.path.SwaggerBootstrap</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

And my pom extract is here:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Good luck;)